# Trouble with Generic List creation

Tags: java, list, generics

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
List<Double> doubles = Arrays.asList(226.6131 , 7789879.3  );
List<Long>  longs  = Arrays.asList( 687643643687L , 743926945627L );
List<List<?>> lists =  Arrays.asList(ints, doubles , longs); // Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<List<? extends Number&Comparable<?>>> to List<List<?>> 
List<List<? extends Number & Comparable<?>>> lists =  Arrays.asList(ints, doubles , longs); // Syntax error on token "&", , expected
```

I am trying to create a List of Lists as the code above shows. First I have 3 lists , each of which stores elements that `extends Number implements Comparable`. Next I want to put the 3 lists into another List , but I am not able to do this.

```
List<List<?>> lists =  Arrays.asList(ints, doubles , longs);
```

This line gives compiler error saying  cannot convert from `List<List<? extends Number&Comparable<?>>>` to `List<List<?>>`  .

When I try to modify the type of reference in next line , there is a syntax error.
How do I get the 3 lists above ( `ints` , `doubles` and `longs` ) into another `List<>` ?

Edit : A related question :
 What is correct syntax of declaring a `List` of `List`s of elements that extends `Number` AND `implement Comparable`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe you want something like:

```
List<? extends List<?>> lists =  Arrays.asList(ints, doubles , longs);
```

you can use this form for more type safety:

```
List<? extends List<? extends Number>> lists =  Arrays.<List<? extends Number>>asList(ints, doubles , longs);
```

Comment: This will not prevent a list `List<String>` from being added to the top list. I want only lists of `Number`s that can be `Comparable`.

Comment: @Bhaskar - i was just telling you how to get rid of the compiler warning.  whether or not it is the bound that _you_ specifically desired is another question.

Comment: you are right - maybe my question is not stated enough clearly , but I want the bounds anyway.

Comment: i added a typesafe variant with a closer bound.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
List<? extends List<? extends Number>> lists
    =  Arrays.asList(ints, doubles , longs);
```

This will still give an unchecked conversion warning, but it provides a slight bit more type safety over the other solutions offered so far.

You can always do this in a type-safe manner by not using `Arrays.asList`:

```
List<List<? extends Number>> lists = new ArrayList<List<? extends Number>>();
lists.add(ints);
lists.add(doubles);
lists.add(longs);
```

Comment: Arrays.asList does not return a java.util.ArrayList.

Comment: @jtahlborn - Take a look at the [source code Arrays.java](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/Collections-Jar-Zip-Logging-regex/java/util/Arrays.java.htm)

Comment: yes, you've proved my point.  look down 2 lines.  it's _not_ java.util.ArrayList, it is java.util.Arrays.ArrayList (an internal impl).

Comment: @jtahlborn Hah! You got me. I didn't notice that inner class. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your second list of compósed by objexts that extends class Number, you can try:

```
List<? extends List<? extends Number>> lists =  Arrays.asList(ints, doubles , longs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend mixing different types in a list. 
If you do want to do it, I think you can try get rid of the generic type in the inner list to hold any objects.

```
List<List> lists =  Arrays.asList(ints, doubles , longs);
```

Comment: I agree that mixing the different list types looks unholy.

Comment: This won't work unless you do a double cast: `(List<List>) (List) Arrays.asList(...)`. I expected I would have to suppress the "unchecked" warning, but it is not present on my machine.  I believe that my Netbeans is having some issues however, and probably `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` should be added.

Answer (score 0):

`List<List<? extends Comparable<? extends Number>>> list = new ArrayList<List<? extends Comparable<? extends Number>>>();`

and

list.add(ints);

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
List<? extends Number> ints = (List<Integer>)Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
List<? extends Number> doubles = (List<Double>)Arrays.asList(226.6131 , 7789879.3  );
List<? extends Number>  longs  = (List<Long>)Arrays.asList( 687643643687L , 743926945627L );
List<List<? extends Number>> lists = Arrays.asList( ints, doubles, longs );
```

It has none of the smells and all of the type safety you can get.

I expect adding `Comparable` would not be difficult.